# Get snapshot date in Microsoft R Open

Tags: r, snapshot, microsoft-r

When the R session starts in RStudio various bits of information are shown some of which are accessible via R.version(), version, sessionInfo() etc. However, when using Microsoft R Open other information is shown such as the default snapshot date being used (each R version being pinned to a snapshot date). I'd like to be able to obtain this date in code but cannot see how to do so, any ideas?
The idea is to be able to store the R version and snapshot date being used alongside results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

packageDescription("RevoUtils", field="MRANDate")

will give you the snapshot date (as shown for MRO 3.4.4):

> packageDescription("RevoUtils", field="MRANDate")
>
> [1] "2018-04-01"

Cheers,
Rich Calaway
Microsoft R Open team